# Behave - Testing using blank Example fields

Tags: python, python-behave

I am using Behave to automate the testing of a config file, as part of this test I need to populate various fields in the config file with invalid and blank fields. Where I am entering values I can do this using a Scenario Outline entering the values in the Examples. However when I try entering a blank field using this method Behave does not like the fact there is no value.

Is there an easy way to pass a blank value from the Examples file, or will I need to test these conditions using a separate behave test

```
feature
    Scenario Outline:Misconfigured Identity Listener
             Given an already stopped Identity Listener
             And parameter <parameter> is configured to value <config_value>
             When the Identity Listener is started
             Then the identity listener process is not present on the system
             And the log contains a <message> showing that the parameter is not configured
            Examples: Protocols
             |parameter                        |message                           |config_value|
             |cache_ip_address                 | cache_ip_address                 |            |
             |cache_ip_address                 | cache_ip_address                 | 123.123.12 |
```

the step where I define the config value

```
@given('parameter {parameter} is configured to value {config_value}')
def step_impl(context, parameter, config_value):
    context.parameter = parameter
    context.config_value = config_value
    context.identity_listener.update_config(parameter, config_value)
```

changing the config file using sed -i (I am interacting with a linux box in this test)

```
 def update_config(self, param, config_value):
        command = 'sudo sh -c "sed -i'
        command = command + " '/" + param + "/c\\" + param + "= "+ config_value + " \\' {0}\""
        command = command.format(self.config_file)
        self.il_ssh.runcmd(command)
```

Thanks to answer from @Verv i got this working solution below

passed an empty value in for fields where I don't want a value passed

```
 |parameter                        |message                           |config_value|
 |cache_ip_address                 | cache_ip_address                 | empty      |
```

Added an if else statement into my update config step

```
def update_config(self, param, config_value):
    if config_value == "empty":
        il_config = ""
    else:
        il_config = config_value

    command = 'sudo sh -c "sed -i'
    command = command + " '/" + param + "/c\\" + param + "= " + il_config + " \\' {0}\""
    command = command.format(self.config_file)
    self.il_ssh.runcmd(command)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put something like `empty` in the field, and tweak your method so that whenever the field's value is `empty`, you treat it as an actual empty string (i.e. `""`)